# Spring integration does not execute second groovy script

Tags: spring, groovy, batch-processing

I use spring integration to execute 2 spring batch executable jar files wrapped in groovy script. If spring integration configured to execute first groovy script and then second it executes only first script and does not executes second. If I reverse it in spring integration configuration it executes second groovy script and does not execute first. My integration configuration is as follows

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"  log-full-message="true"       level="INFO" logger-name="org.springframework"/>
<int:wire-tap channel="logger" />   
 <context:mbean-server />
 <int-jmx:mbean-export/>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="getFile" directory="file:${xmlFileInputDirectory}"
     prevent-duplicates="true" channel="channel1" filename-pattern="Data*">
    <int:poller id="poller" max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000">            
    </int:poller>

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="channel1">
    <int:interceptors>
         <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="channe2">
<int:interceptors>
         <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>     
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channe2">                 
    <int-groovy:script>
        <![CDATA[
            def proc = "java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml -jar one.jar".execute();
            proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>        
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channe2">                 
    <int-groovy:script>
        <![CDATA[
            def proc = "java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml -jar two.jar --data.dictionary.path=data.csv".execute();
            proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>        
</int:service-activator>          


<int:message-history/>  


<bean id="mainClass"
    class="com.company.Main" />
```

My main class that starts first batch job looks like this:

```
    public final class Main {   

private Main() { }


public static void main(final String... args) {

    final AbstractApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/int_file");  
    context.start();


}
```

}

My first batch job main class looks like this:

```
    public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws ... {        

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Doesn't `System.exit(0)` kill the JVM?

Comment: The main integration flow is still alive. If I drop next file it will execute the first job again and does not execute second. Maybe integration thinks that first groovy script is not finished yet. Maybe somebody can help how integration detects when it is time to launch next script in my situation.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. To start second task spring integration needs a return value from first task. So this groovy script works def            command = "java -jar one.jar"
                def process = command.execute()
                def exitVal = process.waitFor()                
                println exitVal
                return exitVal